# Hamburger menu in navbar wont open nor close using bootstrap in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm running into a little problem that I can't figure out. Perhaps you guys can?

I am working on a small project for a kind of dashboard/forum-like website, but I have the problem that my navbar won't open/close and I don't understand why.

I am using ReactJS and Bootstrap for this.
I have used numerous examples both on blogs online and from Bootstrap itself. Still somehow it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
  );
```

**App.jsx:**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';

import Home from './components/Home';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import Login from './components/Login';
import PageNotFound from "./utils/pagenotfound";

import Nav from './components/Nav';

const App = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <Nav />
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/profile/:id" element={<Profile />}/>
              <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Routes>
      </div>
   )
}

export default App;
```

**Component Nav:**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from '../media/logo.png';
import "../Navbar.css";

const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="container collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
                        <img src={logo} alt="x" style={{ height: 35, width: 35 }} />
                    </Link>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to={"/"}>Dashboard</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to={"/Home"}>News</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to={"/profile:"}>Profile</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to={"/Login"}>Login</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link className="nav-link" to={"/"}>Logout</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn0PK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfD74.png)

Hope anyone can help me with this issue :(

I expected to have a navbar which collaps and opens when I press the hamburger button

Comment: You need to use a version of Bootstrap made for React.  Try https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/

Comment: Ohh snap hahaha didn't know that excisted npm i bootstrap doesnt work in react?